# How to use data from a variable inside a method in a different method (both methods in the same class)?

Tags: c#, .net, object, methods, oauth-2.0

I would like to reuse *OAuth2Parameters parameters* from the First method in the Second method. Here's the code:

```
public class SomeController : ApiController
    {
        public string First()
        {
            OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();

            parameters.ClientId = "someClientID";
            parameters.ClientSecret = "someClientSecret";
            parameters.RedirectUri = "someRedirectUri";
            parameters.Scope = "someScope";

            string authorizationUrl = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);

            return authorizationUrl;
        }

        public void Second(string someAccessCode)
        {
            // I want to reuse the above OAuth2Parameters parameters here:
            parameters.AccessCode = someAccessCode;

            OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);
            string accessToken = parameters.AccessToken;
        }
    }
```

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a member field for the class, if the first method is always called before the second one.

```
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    OAuth2Parameters parameters;

    public string First()
    {
        string authorizationUrl = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);

        return authorizationUrl;
    }

    public void Second(string someAccessCode)
    {
        // I want to reuse the above OAuth2Parameters parameters here:
        parameters.AccessCode = someAccessCode;

        OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);
        string accessToken = parameters.AccessToken;
    }
}
```

If you're not sure, use a property with backing field.

```
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    OAuth2Parameters _parameters;

    private OAuthParameters {
      get {
        if (_parameters == null) {
          _parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();

          _parameters .ClientId = "someClientID";
          _parameters .ClientSecret = "someClientSecret";
          _parameters .RedirectUri = "someRedirectUri";
          _parameters .Scope = "someScope";
        }

        return _parameters;
      }
    }

    public string First()
    {
        string authorizationUrl = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(OAuthParameters);

        return authorizationUrl;
    }

    public void Second(string someAccessCode)
    {
        // I want to reuse the above OAuth2Parameters parameters here:
        parameters.AccessCode = someAccessCode;

        OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(OAuthParameters);
        string accessToken = OAuthParameters.AccessToken;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..Declare variable above First() so that it will available for both method

```
OAuth2Parameters parameters; 
public string First() {  parameters = new OAuth2Parameters(); ....
```

Comment: @Marko: Your first suggestion throws an error and there's something wrong with your private OAuthParameters. Instead I put OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters(); directly under my class, but now this line: OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(OAuthParameters); throws me this error: An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.